# Where to store DB files for SQL Failover Cluster Instance on Hyper-V

Tags: sql-server, clustering, virtualisation

I am upgrading old off-lease hardware to brand new / full warranty enterprise-class host servers and 10gb iSCSI SAN. In the old environment, it was made up of a bunch of old Dell servers with lots of flash and SSD storage serving up everything over SMB for both VMs and SQL FCI storage. (Performance has been phenomenal, but I've been living one failed piece of hardware away from catastrophe for 4+ years)

The overall virtualization environment is now Windows Server 2022 running Hyper V in a 3-host cluster. The 2 SQL VMs are Server 2019 with SQL 2017 in a failover group.

All hosts and VM storage have been migrated over to the new iSCSI SAN, but the SQL files are still stored over the network on the old Dell host with all of the flash and SSD. In a Hyper-V environment, what is the best way to handle the shared storage requirements for SQL FCI?

I've searched heavily and not come across anything conclusive, most recent documentation is on running FCI in Azure. I have considered several options:

1. SAN is Dell Unity, so I can do a NAS share and continue using SMB, but I would need to add another network adapter to the SAN to keep the networking segregated properly, which I am open to, but I'd rather just have the SAN do all block storage.
2. Shared VHDX - Not sure if this is the best approach, but would work at the host level and not require anything funky in the SQL VMs
3. CSV in SQL Failover Group - This would require iSCSI initiators in the VMs, which I don't know if that is best practice or not? Seems like that gets ugly at the networking layer.

Is there anything else that I should be considering that I have not? How are other people handling this type of a situation?

*Also worth noting, I'm not looking for shared-nothing AGs, the environment hosts over a dozen 3rd party system DBs which are heavily reliant on SQL Agent, so FCI is the preferred option.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the most appropriate answer here is using a VHD Set in a CSV configuration: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/vhd-set-feature-in-microsoft-windows-server-2016/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an obvious choice, which is to present shared block volumes directly to each VM using iSCSI.  This requires no special Hyper-V configuration, or CSV: just your VMs working with your SAN.

Comment: That's partially what I intended with option 3 above, I couldn't find anything that said whether doing iSCSI initiators directly in the VMs were for or against best practices?